# What is curious badge and why I am not getting it?

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

Well this is simple, from couple of months it shows that

```
next badge: Curious 9/5
```

So I already crossed limit of 5 questions, I am having 9, but I am not getting this badge from months and it is stuck here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The full badge description is:

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record

A ["positive question record"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/145982) is defined as:

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

I won't post the exact number here for privacy, but yours is under 0.5. The problem is if you have a downvoted or closed question that you delete (which I would categorize as a good thing), it actually counts against you more because you still have a downvoted/closed question, but now you also have a deleted question. Not entirely sure why they designed it that way, but it can result in single questions penalizing you up to three times.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much can mods see about deleted questions? If I got it right, a regular user can't even see all of their own deleted questions, just the "recent" ones?

Comment: @ilkkachu Deleted posts show up in the list on a profile page for mods, just styled differently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XHUq.png. I don't remember the details on what users can see on profiles; it used to be nothing but then they did something with "recent" deletions

Comment: @ilkkachu - 10k can see deleted Q's. See the A'er for ways that they're able to - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117892/how-do-you-view-deleted-questions.

Comment: @slm Not on profiles though, as far as I know?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - correct.

Comment: The idea is that we want to reward asking useful questions without encouraging people to flood the site with questions. Self-deleting closed or downvoted questions is a good idea, but even better is not asking at all. Best of all is editing the question so that it can be reopened and upvoted.

Comment: What about duplicate questions?

Comment: @JonEricson, isn't the thing here that the equation would endorse _not deleting_ closed or negatively scored questions? Of course it would be better to not have them in the first place, but if you've done that and noticed it was a mistake, the only way to make it better it is to delete the Q. And then you get penalized (more) for doing just that. Doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: @ilkkachu: If this were the _primary_ way the badges were determined, I'd agree with you. But instead, the badge is given out for regularly asking good questions on the site. Most people are not impacted by this restriction at all. For the few who are, not self-deleting isn't really going to help since other people (and the system itself) will delete for you. Instead, the best thing to do is edit old questions and be more careful asking new ones.

Comment: @PRY: I considered making an exception for duplicate questions, but decided that worked against the spirit of the badges. Duplicates [sometimes help people find the information they are looking for](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), but the goal of the badge is to encourage new questions.

Comment: @ilkkachu AFAIK a closed question or a negatively scored question with no answers will get deleted eventually, so by deleting it yourself you don't get penalized more, you just speed up the process. The way to get penalized less is to delete a poor question before it gets closed.